# flash as3 draw a donut wedge (arc with inner and outer radius) using curveTo

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, drawing

I'm trying to draw an arc in flash using a minimal amount of code / iterations. I ported this method below from an old AS2 example, but it requires a loop through a number of steps to make it look smooth, and I'd rather avoid that. I saw AS3 has a "curveTo" command, but it doesn't really draw a circular arc, it draws a bezier curve. Is there an arc command in flash? or a way to draw a segment of a circle?

Here's my old code:

```
function drawSolidArc (drawObj:Object, centerX:Number,centerY:Number,innerRadius:Number,outerRadius:Number,startAngle:Number,arcAngle:Number,steps:int=20):void {
    if (Math.abs(startAngle)>360)startAngle%=360
    if (Math.abs(arcAngle)>360)arcAngle%=360
    startAngle/=360,arcAngle/=360
    var twoPI:Number = 2 * Math.PI;
    var angleStep:Number = arcAngle/steps;
    var angle:Number, i:int, endAngle:Number;
    var xx:Number = centerX + Math.cos(startAngle * twoPI) * innerRadius;
    var yy:Number = centerY + Math.sin(startAngle * twoPI) * innerRadius;
    var xxInit:Number=xx;
    var yyInit:Number=yy;
    drawObj.graphics.moveTo(xx,yy);
    for(i=1; i<=steps; i++) {
        angle = (startAngle + i * angleStep) * twoPI;
        xx = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * innerRadius;
        yy = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * innerRadius;
        drawObj.graphics.lineTo(xx,yy);
    }
    endAngle = startAngle + arcAngle;
    for(i=0;i<=steps;i++) {
        angle = (endAngle - i * angleStep) * twoPI;
        xx = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * outerRadius;
        yy = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * outerRadius;
        drawObj.graphics.lineTo(xx,yy);
    }

    drawObj.graphics.lineTo(xxInit,yyInit);
};

var myArc:Shape = new Shape(); //or another DisplayObject

myArc.graphics.beginFill(0xcccccc, 0.50);
//objName, centerX,centerY, innerRadius, outerRadius, startAngle (12 o'clock is -90), arcAngle (degrees from startAngle), steps (smoothness)
drawSolidArc (myArc,250, 250, 180, 200, -90, 65, 100);
myArc.graphics.endFill();
this.addChild(myArc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to Jeremy's solution, although I didn't mask it. Apparently if you create another arc of a smaller radius from the same center point, it will subtract from the existing shape, so I just made another call to drawSolidArc after the first, and before endFill, with zero as the centerpoint, and the outer radius being the desired inner radius of the first wedge:

```
var myArc:Sprite = new Sprite();
myArc.graphics.beginFill(0xcccccc, 1);
drawArc(myArc, 275, 200, 60, 150, 35); //spriteName, startX, startY, innerRadius, radius, arcAngle, startAngle
drawArc(myArc, 275, 200, 0, 60, 35); //subtract out the middle by drawing a new circle over the top of it
myArc.graphics.endFill();
this.addChild(myArc);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Graphics.cubicCurveTo()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#cubicCurveTo%28%29) will give you a better approximation of an arc than `curveTo`. But it's still not perfect.

Comment: I don't see any function named cubicCurveTo in the documentation and when I attempt to use that function I get errors.

Comment: Just follow the link ;) 
Language Version:  ActionScript 3.0
Runtime Versions:  Flash Player 11, AIR 3

Comment: I can't even publish to flash player 11 in CS5 - not really a viable option for me right now. I saw an MXP that adds this functionality but you must be running as an admin on the computer to install it, which also isn't an option for me at work. But it will be nice to have a more accurate curve method in newer versions of flash.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know you compiled with Flash.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have done it:

Draw a doughnut and mask it:

```
_foreground = new Sprite();
_foreground.graphics.beginFill(_colour)
_foreground.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, _outerRadius);
_foreground.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, _innerRadius);
_foreground.graphics.endFill();
_container.addChild(_foreground);

_mask = new Sprite();
_mask.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
_foreground.mask = _mask;
```

Then draw it using this method - by drawing a wedge into the mask

```
private function draw(e:Event):void //Called each frame (if animating)
{
// No need to draw more than 360
if (Math.abs(_arc) > _endAngle) 
{
    _arc = _endAngle;
    stop();
}

_numOfSegs = Math.ceil(Math.abs(_arc) / 45);
_segAngle = _arc / _numOfSegs;
_segAngle = (_segAngle / 180) * Math.PI;
_angle = (_startAngle / 180) * Math.PI;

// Calculate the start point
_ax = Math.cos(_angle) * _outerRadius;
_ay = Math.sin(-_angle) * _outerRadius;

// Draw the first line
_mask.graphics.lineTo(_ax, _ay);

for (var i:int=0; i<_numOfSegs; i++) 
{
    _angle += _segAngle;
    _angleMid = _angle - (_segAngle / 2);
    _bx = Math.cos(_angle) * _outerRadius;
    _by = Math.sin(_angle) * _outerRadius;
    _cx = Math.cos(_angleMid) * (_outerRadius / Math.cos(_segAngle / 2));
    _cy = Math.sin(_angleMid) * (_outerRadius / Math.cos(_segAngle / 2));
    _mask.graphics.curveTo(_cx, _cy, _bx, _by);
}

// Close the wedge
_mask.graphics.lineTo(0, 0);
_arc += 3.6; //This gives a 100 steps to complete the circle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a link to few different shape drawing classes I've written. You can achieve the desired segment of a circle by drawing a wedge and masking out the center of it with a second circle shape.

https://github.com/makemachine/makemachine.actionscript/tree/master/src/makemachine/display/shapes

Comment: Thanks - this is a nice library.

Answer (score 0):

Then there's [this implementation](http://www.funky-monkey.nl/blog/2010/04/20/drawing-shapes-in-as3-a-class-to-draw-an-arc-star-gear-cog-wedge-and-a-burst/). But it's almost as messy, as that which you've posted. I'm afraid there's no elegant way (few lines or so) of drawing an arc.